# How can I enter Unicode characters (e.g. ♥♦♣♠) when logging into Windows?

Tags: windows-8, passwords, login, typing

As far as I can tell, it is possible to put a ♥ character in a Windows user password. The problem is, when you get to the log on screen, how can this be typed?

As far as I can tell, any symbol that is of the form <kbd>Alt</kbd>+xyz, but the ♥ character for example is only <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd>.

How can I type this character (and others like it) at logon?

Comment: Try Alt + number pad keys. This used to work on older versions of windows. I don't have windows 8 or a number pad to test this though

Comment: @FDinoff that is what I am doing now. It will not let me do Alt + single number

Comment: I'd advise against it, simply because being able to enter them is so iffy, and may well depend on the particular computer and browser version you're using.  (But if you're using a computer that does not have the separate keypad, remember you need to do "Num Lock" before you type the key combo on the M-9 keys of the simulated keypad array.)

Comment: @DanielRHicks This is for windows login on a laptop. It will always have a num pad.

Comment: @soandos try padding with 0s?

Comment: @FDinoff, I tried. I think the zeros change the symbols though in general Ã├ (0963,963)

Comment: FYI alt-codes enter characters from your current codepage, not unicode.  You need to [set a flag in the registry](http://superuser.com/questions/655631) to use unicode alt-codes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On Windows 8 logon screen you just have to be really fast to type ♥ in password field. Don't hold the <kbd>Alt</kbd> for too long. I don't know how fast are your fingers, but you can probably forget about codes longer than 3 characters.

Besides those characters are obviously not supported I would not advice to use them, because they won't add as much entropy as you may expect.

Comment: About the entropy : https://xkcd.com/936/